# Is it possible to install OS X on an assembled desktop?

Tags: install, macos

I've recently purchased an assembled desktop (it has an i5 processor, and a intel DH67CL motherboard). Is it possible for me to install OS X on a separate partition, just to understand the experience of working in OS X? I don't mind if its a trial installation (which won't work after X days), but I need to understand whether working on OS X would suit me. I'm 60+, and have used Windows all my life, hence the hesitation before buying a MacBook.

Comment: Theoretically you can install OS X on non-Apple machine. However, this is against the OS X TOS. Such a machine is called Hackintosh and there are several guides on the internet about how to do this. However, I am not sure if that motherboard is compatible, and from what I remember other components (e.g. video card) should also be compatible. The process is much more trickier than normal install of OS X on Apple machine or Windows on a PC. And this question most likely will be closed as  Hackintosh-related.

Comment: Can't edit my comment, but it should be OS X EULA, not TOS.

Comment: As everything you're doing falls into the "grey zone" of legality anyway the easiest way to try out OSX on a Windows machine is to download a preinstalled OSX VMWare image from any of the popular torrent sites and use that.

Comment: As per the FAQ, questions like this (which ask how to violate the terms of the license) are explicitly outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

1) OS X doesn't have any of that licensing/trial bs you're probably used to. There is just 1 version of OS X that you run, and that's it.
2) OS X can't just run on regular hardware without being "tricked" into thinking it's a mac
3) What's you're trying to do is against Apple's EULA, but is possible. You should see the [Hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com) project, and the [OS X 86](http://www.osx86project.org) project.
4) Running OS X on standard hardware is a very common feat, which is well documented on the internet… all you need is a simple google search query.

Answer (score -2):

You can install Mountain Lion from the following link (doesn't even require you to burn a new DVD!):

http://geeknizer.com/make-bootable-usb-mountain-lion-install-disk-drive/

Comment: And how would this be helpful to install OS X on non-Apple hardware?

Comment: Only works for booting on macs...